# expl3 sequence of property lists with parameterized names: spurious space

Tags: expl3, l3prop, l3seq

### Edit (context)

For a class `myclass` I'm working on, I want the user be able to specify (the characteristics of) the institute, subinstitute, subsubinstitute, etc. he is affiliated to. Because the number of (sub(sub(...)))institutes is unpredictable, I want the user to be able to specify these characteristics through a single command, say `\setinstitute` with `⟨key⟩ = ⟨value⟩` syntax:

```
\setinstitute{
  name      = ⟨name⟩,
  url       = ⟨url⟩,
  logo file = ⟨logo file⟩,
}
```

that may be used as many times as necessary.

For the `⟨key⟩ = ⟨value⟩` syntax, I'm using the `l3keys` module and its nice `.prop_put:N` syntax:

```
\keys_define:nn { myclass/institute }
{
  name        .prop_put:N = \l_tmpa_prop,
  url         .prop_put:N = \l_tmpa_prop,
  logo~ file  .prop_put:N = \l_tmpa_prop,
}
```

Hence, the characteristics of the institutes are stored in property list(s).

Now, the order of the institutes specified should tell the "depth" of each of them and I have to be able to retrieve e.g. the name of the 3<sup>rd</sup> institute. Hence a sequence, say `\g__myclass_institutes_seq`:

```
\NewDocumentCommand \setinstitute { m } {
  \keys_set:nn { myclass/institute } { #1 }
  \seq_gput_left:Nn \g__myclass_institutes_seq { \l_tmpa_prop }
}
```

The point is, it is always the same temporary property list which is used and the sequence contains only multiple replications of the last entered characteristics. Hence, property lists with variable names which are made equal to the temporary one before being added to the sequence:

```
\int_new:N \g__myclass_institutes_number_int

\NewDocumentCommand \setinstitute { m } {
  \keys_set:nn { myclass/institute } { #1 }
  \int_gincr:N \g__myclass_institutes_number_int
  \__myclass_populate_institutes_seq:n {
    \int_use:N \g__myclass_institutes_number_int
  }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__myclass_populate_institutes_seq:n #1
{
  \prop_new:c {l__myclass_institute_#1_prop}
  \prop_set_eq:cN {l__myclass_institute_#1_prop} \l_tmpa_prop
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  % The 3 following lines of code were wrong         %
  % and are replaced by the ones suggested by @egreg %
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  % \seq_gput_left:Nn \g__myclass_institutes_seq {
  %   \l__myclass_institute_#1_prop
  % }
  \seq_gput_left:Nx \g__myclass_institutes_seq {
    \exp_not:c {l__myclass_institute_#1_prop}
  }
}
```

Here is a complete example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{myclass.cls}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ProvidesExplClass
  {myclass}
  {2020/07/10}
  {0.1}
  {
    My~Nice~Class.%
  }
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass { article }
%
\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \l__myclass_institute_prop
\seq_new:N \g__myclass_institutes_seq
\int_new:N \g__myclass_institutes_number_int

\keys_define:nn { myclass/institute }
{
  name         .prop_put:N = \l_tmpa_prop,
  url          .prop_put:N = \l_tmpa_prop,
  logo~ file   .prop_put:N = \l_tmpa_prop,
}

\NewDocumentCommand \setinstitute { m } {
  \keys_set:nn { myclass/institute } { #1 }
  \int_gincr:N \g__myclass_institutes_number_int
  \__myclass_populate_institutes_seq:n {
    \int_use:N \g__myclass_institutes_number_int
  }
}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__myclass_populate_institutes_seq:n #1
{
  \prop_new:c {l__myclass_institute_#1_prop}
  \prop_set_eq:cN {l__myclass_institute_#1_prop} \l_tmpa_prop
  \prop_clear:N \l_tmpa_prop
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  % The 3 following lines of code were wrong         %
  % and are replaced by the ones suggested by @egreg %
  %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  % \seq_gput_left:Nn \g__myclass_institutes_seq {
  %   \l__myclass_institute_#1_prop
  % }
  \seq_gput_left:Nx \g__myclass_institutes_seq {
    \exp_not:c {l__myclass_institute_#1_prop}
  }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \displayinstitutes {  } {
  \seq_reverse:N \g__myclass_institutes_seq
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \g__myclass_institutes_seq {
    \begin{description}
    \item[Institute~##1:]\
      % \prop_show:N ##2
      \begin{description}
        \prop_map_inline:Nn ##2 {
        \item[####1:]####2
        }
      \end{description}
    \end{description}
  }
}

\ProcessKeysOptions { myclass }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
\setinstitute{
  name      = foo1,
  url       = bar1,
  logo file = baz1,
}
\setinstitute{
  name      = foo2,
  url       = bar2,
  logo file = baz2,
}
\displayinstitutes
\end{document}
```

But it is far from impossible that I misused `expl3` here.

### Original post

I'm trying to create an `expl3` sequence of property lists, the names of the latter being parameterized (containing an integer parameter): `\l_#1_prop`. It is easy to add entries to such property lists thanks to the `c` specifier:

```
\prop_put:cnn {l_#1_prop} {key} {value}
```

Because `\seq_put_left:Nc` doesn't exist (and isn't accepted as a variant), I tried to add to the sequences the property lists with `\l_#1_prop`:

```
  \seq_put_left:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {
    \l_#1_prop
  }
```

but this results in sequence items as `\l_ #1_prop` (note the spurious space) instead of `\l_#1_prop`.

This is exemplified by the following MCE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \test { m m } {
  \prop_new:c {l_#1_prop}
  \prop_put:cnn {l_#1_prop} {key} {#2}
  \seq_put_left:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {
    \l_#1_prop
  }
  \prop_show:c {l_#1_prop}
  \seq_show:N \l_tmpa_seq
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\test{1}{a}
\end{document}
```

the shown property list and sequence giving respectively `\l_1_prop` and `\l_ 1_prop`:

```
The property list \l_1_prop contains the pairs (without outer braces):
>  {key}  =>  {a}.
<recently read> }
                 
l.17 \test{1}{a}
                
? 
The sequence \l_tmpa_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {\l_ 1_prop}.
<recently read> }
                 
l.17 \test{1}{a}
                
?
```

Do you know where the spurious space is coming from and how to get rid of it?

Comment: You want to put a property list inside a sequence? There is no spurious space, the item in the sequence consists of the seven tokens `\l_•1•_•p•r•o•p` (the bullet just separates tokens).

Comment: `\seq_put_left:Nx \l_tmpa_seq { \exp_not:c { l_#1_prop } }` Of course you should use a better name for your variables. And I see no real reason to put the property list in the sequence, when `#1` suffices.

Comment: tex always shows a space after command sequences with letters in their name, the space after `\_` is the same as the space after `\zz` in `\def\foo{\zz1}\show\foo
> \foo=macro:
->\zz 1.
`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see no reason to put the entire property list in the sequence: just put the index and when you need to retrieve something from the property list you can use the index, say with

```
\prop_item:cn { l_ \seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {1} _ prop} } { foo }
```

in order to obtain the property `foo` from the property list with the index stored in the first position of the sequence.

Anyway, if you want to store the full name, you can do

```
\seq_put_left:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \exp_not:c { l_#1_prop } }
```

What you see is not a spurious space. You're storing as the sequence item several tokens

```
\l_•1•_•p•r•o•p
```

(bullets just separate tokens for clarity) and TeX always adds a space after a control word when asked to `\show` some token list.

---

#### Update

Here's an edited version of your code where I show how you can just store the index.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{myclass.cls}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ProvidesExplClass
  {myclass}
  {2020/07/10}
  {0.1}
  {
    My~Nice~Class.
  }
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass { article }

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \l__myclass_institute_prop
\prop_new:N \l__myclass_tmpa_prop
\seq_new:N \g__myclass_institutes_seq
\int_new:N \g__myclass_institutes_number_int

\keys_define:nn { myclass/institute }
 {
  name         .prop_put:N = \l__myclass_tmpa_prop,
  url          .prop_put:N = \l__myclass_tmpa_prop,
  logo~ file   .prop_put:N = \l__myclass_tmpa_prop,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \setinstitute { m }
 {
  \prop_clear:N \l__myclass_tmpa_prop
  \keys_set:nn { myclass/institute } { #1 }
  \int_gincr:N \g__myclass_institutes_number_int
  \__myclass_populate_institutes_seq:V \g__myclass_institutes_number_int
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__myclass_populate_institutes_seq:n #1
 {
  \prop_new:c {l__myclass_institute_#1_prop}
  \prop_set_eq:cN {l__myclass_institute_#1_prop} \l__myclass_tmpa_prop
  \seq_gput_left:Nn \g__myclass_institutes_seq { #1 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__myclass_populate_institutes_seq:n { V }

\NewDocumentCommand \displayinstitutes {  }
 {
  \seq_set_eq:NN \l_tmpa_seq \g__myclass_institutes_seq
  \seq_reverse:N \l_tmpa_seq
  \seq_map_indexed_inline:Nn \l_tmpa_seq
   {
    \begin{description}
    \item[Institute~##1:]\mbox{}
    %\prop_show:c { l__myclass_institute_##2_prop }
      \begin{description}
        \prop_map_inline:cn { l__myclass_institute_##2_prop }
         {
          \item[####1:]####2
         }
      \end{description}
    \end{description}
   }
 }

\ProcessKeysOptions { myclass }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
\setinstitute{
  name      = foo1,
  url       = bar1,
  logo file = baz1,
}
\setinstitute{
  name      = foo2,
  url       = bar2,
  logo file = baz2,
}
\displayinstitutes
\end{document}
```

However, since the index is just a number which is incremented at each call of `\setinstitute`, you don't even need the sequence: just call the property list by the index.

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{myclass.cls}
\RequirePackage{l3keys2e}
\RequirePackage{expl3}
\RequirePackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\ProvidesExplClass
  {myclass}
  {2020/07/10}
  {0.1}
  {
    My~Nice~Class.
  }
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\LoadClass { article }

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \l__myclass_institute_prop
\prop_new:N \l__myclass_tmpa_prop
\int_new:N \g__myclass_institutes_number_int

\keys_define:nn { myclass/institute }
 {
  name         .prop_put:N = \l__myclass_tmpa_prop,
  url          .prop_put:N = \l__myclass_tmpa_prop,
  logo~ file   .prop_put:N = \l__myclass_tmpa_prop,
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \setinstitute { m }
 {
  \prop_clear:N \l__myclass_tmpa_prop
  \keys_set:nn { myclass/institute } { #1 }
  \int_gincr:N \g__myclass_institutes_number_int
  \prop_new:c {l__myclass_institute_ \int_use:N \g__myclass_institutes_number_int _prop}
  \prop_set_eq:cN
   {l__myclass_institute_ \int_use:N \g__myclass_institutes_number_int _prop}
   \l__myclass_tmpa_prop
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \displayinstitutes {  }
 {
  \int_step_inline:nn { \g__myclass_institutes_number_int }
   {
    \begin{description}
    \item[Institute~##1:]\mbox{}
    %\prop_show:c { l__myclass_institute_##1_prop }
      \begin{description}
        \prop_map_inline:cn { l__myclass_institute_##1_prop }
         {
          \item[####1:]####2
         }
      \end{description}
    \end{description}
   }
 }

\ProcessKeysOptions { myclass }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{myclass}
\begin{document}
\setinstitute{
  name      = foo1,
  url       = bar1,
  logo file = baz1,
}
\setinstitute{
  name      = foo2,
  url       = bar2,
  logo file = baz2,
}
\displayinstitutes
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is far from impossible that I misused `expl3` here. I'll edit my question in order to explain the context.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean by "just put the index" and if it is suitable in my context (detailed in my edited question). Anyway, `\seq_put_left:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \exp_not:c { l_#1_prop } }` (except `\l_tmpa_tl` which should be `\l_tmpa_seq` I guess) works like a charm!

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I added my versions of your code.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `\int_step_inline:nn`: thanks for sharing! Do you really know by heart every one of the thousands of `expl3` commands?! :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé No, but I've used them a lot.